# Undefined class constant 'ROLE_DEFAULT' when register new user SYMFONY 4

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, entity, symfony4

I'm trying to build a login/register controller for users but i get Underfined class constant 'ROLE_DEFAULT' when I register new user.

In my UserController, I have this function to register new user:

> //src/Controller/UserController

```
public function registerAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    // 1) build the form
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    // 2) handle the submit (will only happen on POST)
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // 3) Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
        $password = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword());
        $user->setPassword($password);
        $apiKey = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, rand(1,9999));
        $user->setApiKey($apiKey);
        $user->setEnabled(1);
        // $user->setSuperadmin(true);
        $user->addRole("ROLE_DEFAULT");
        // 4) save the User!
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();


        dump($user);
        exit;

    }

    return $this->render(
        'user/register.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

The error appear when "$user->addRole("ROLE_DEFAULT");" and this is the screenshot:
[image]

> //src/Entity/User:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $lastname;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true)
 */
private $apiKey;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="enabled", type="boolean")
 */
protected $enabled;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="SUPERADMIN", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
protected $superadmin;


/**
 * The salt to use for hashing
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $salt;

/**
 * Encrypted password. Must be persisted.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * Encrypted password. Must be persisted.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="plainPassword", type="string", nullable=false)
 */
protected $plainPassword;


/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $lastLogin;

/**
 * Random string sent to the user email address in order to verify it
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $confirmationToken;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $passwordRequestedAt;




public function __construct()
{
    $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    $this->enabled = false;
    // $this->locked = false;
    $this->roles = array();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return (string) $this->getUsername();
}



public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

// USERNAME//
//===========================================================
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

// EMAIL//
//===========================================================
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}




// API KEY//
//===========================================================
public function getApiKey()
{
    return $this->apiKey;
}
public function setApiKey($apiKey)
{
    return $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
}

// PASSWORD//
//===========================================================
/**
 * Gets the encrypted password.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Gets the encrypted password.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlainPassword()
{
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

public function setPlainPassword($password)
{
    $this->plainPassword = $password;
}



// SALT//
//===========================================================
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    return $this->salt = $salt;
}

// LAST LOGIN//
//===========================================================
/**
 * Gets the last login time.
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getLastLogin()
{
    return $this->lastLogin;
}

public function setLastLogin(\DateTime $time = null)
{
    $this->lastLogin = $time;

    return $this;
}

// CONFIRMATION TOKEN//
//===========================================================
public function getConfirmationToken()
{
    return $this->confirmationToken;
}

public function setConfirmationToken($confirmationToken)
{
    $this->confirmationToken = $confirmationToken;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    $this->plainPassword = null;
}


// ROLES//
//===========================================================
// public function getRoles()
// {
//     return array('ROLE_USER');
// }
/**
 * Returns the user roles
 *
 * @return array The roles
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = array();
    $nameRole                       = $this->idRole->getNamerole();
    $stationCreate                  = $this->idRole->getStationCreate();
    $configurationstationEdit       = $this->idRole->getConfigurationstationEdit();
    $stationEditor                  = $this->idRole->getDatastationEdit();
    $stationValidate                = $this->idRole->getStationValidate();
    $newdataCreate                  = $this->idRole->getNewdataCreate();
    $superadmin                     = $this->superadmin;


    if($stationCreate){
        $roles = array_merge($roles, array('ROLE_CREATOR'));
    }

    if($configurationstationEdit){
        $roles = array_merge($roles, array('ROLE_CONFIGURATOR'));
    }

    if($stationEditor){
        $roles = array_merge($roles, array('ROLE_EDITOR'));
    }

    if($stationValidate){
        $roles = array_merge($roles, array('ROLE_VALIDATOR'));
    }

    if($newdataCreate){
        $roles = array_merge($roles, array('ROLE_MANAGE'));
    }

    if($superadmin){
        $roles = array_merge($roles, array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN'));
    }

    //echo $nameRole." -- ".$stationCreate." -- ".$configurationstationEdit." -- ".$stationValidate." -- ".$newdataCreate;
    //exit;
    //dump($this->idRole);
    //exit;
    // we need to make sure to have at least one role
    $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

    return array_unique($roles);
}


public function setRoles(array $roles)
{
    $this->roles = array();

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        $this->addRole($role);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeRole($role)
{
    if (false !== $key = array_search(strtoupper($role), $this->roles, true)) {
        unset($this->roles[$key]);
        $this->roles = array_values($this->roles);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function hasRole($role)
{
    return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
}

public function addRole($role)
{
    $role = strtoupper($role);
    if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }

    return $this;
}

// ENABLED//
//===========================================================
public function isEnabled()
{
    return $this->enabled;
}

public function setEnabled($boolean)
{
    $this->enabled = (Boolean) $boolean;

    return $this;
}


// SUPERADMIN//
//===========================================================
public function isSuperAdmin()
{
    return $this->hasRole(static::ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN);
}

public function setSuperAdmin($boolean)
{
    if (true === $boolean) {
        $this->addRole(static::ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN);
    } else {
        $this->removeRole(static::ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN);
    }

    return $this;
}

// PASSWORD REQUEST AT//
//===========================================================
/**
 * Gets the timestamp that the user requested a password reset.
 *
 * @return null|\DateTime
 */
public function getPasswordRequestedAt()
{
    return $this->passwordRequestedAt;
}

public function isPasswordRequestNonExpired($ttl)
{
    return $this->getPasswordRequestedAt() instanceof \DateTime &&
           $this->getPasswordRequestedAt()->getTimestamp() + $ttl > time();
}

// EXTRA FUNCTIONS//
//===========================================================

/**
 * Serializes the user.
 *
 * The serialized data have to contain the fields used during check for
 * changes and the id.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->username,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
    ));
}

/**
 * Unserializes the user.
 *
 * @param string $serialized
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    $data = unserialize($serialized);
    // add a few extra elements in the array to ensure that we have enough keys when unserializing
    // older data which does not include all properties.
    $data = array_merge($data, array_fill(0, 2, null));

    list(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->username,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
        $this->email,
    ) = $data;
}
}
```

And the security.yml file

> //config/packages/security.yml

```
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    user:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            # property: apiKey
            property: username
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: true
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: user

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
    # form_login:
    #     login_path: security_login
    #     check_path: security_login
    #     csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
    #     default_target_path: userRedirectAction

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I want to know what I'm doing wrong or where can i find a good guide to build a login/register system in SYMFONY 4.

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is actually in User::getRoles() $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT; You copy pasted without defining the class constant.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I noticed is use of `static` to (presumably) get constant. If that was the intention, it is not right.

See this comment of PHP constatnt official docs to get a grasp of what could go wrong:

**[PHP Constant - self/static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#114143)**

But, regardless, what I could not see was the constant itself defined within the `User` class, which I saw belonged to your namespace.

So, in order to use it, please define it like:

```
class User
{
    const ROLE_DEFAULT = "ROLE_DEFAULT";

    // ....
    // The rest of your code 
}
```

And then use it like:

```
if ($role === self::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
    return $this;
}
```

Though, I am not sure why would you attempt to add that role in your controller at the first place, however, I leave to you to you to decide.

Hope this helps a bit...